# Es correcto el algoritmo?

Tags: javascript

*Hice este código para probar un número al azar:*

```js
function a(n){
  var b = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (parseInt(n) - n/4) + n/4));
  
  return b;
}

console.log(a(20));
```

***Mi duda es sí todos los números tienen la misma oportunidad de salir ,y como puedo comprobarlo¿?***

**Ya que probandolo no me salió ningún 10 en más de 20 veces**

Comment: Todos tienen la misma probabilidad de salir, ya que no estás dando ninguna preferencia por unos u otros. A mí si que me ha salido un 10, solo es cuestión de paciencia... o suerte ;)

Comment: y como lo compruebo ?

Comment: Realmente ahí tendrías que realizar cálculos estadísticos que yo personalmente no sé realizar. Tendrías que preguntarle a algún matemático o ingeniero con conocimientos de probabilidad sobre que cálculos realizar para poder establecer que probabilidad tiene cada opción de salir, aunque, si no estoy confundido, al tener todos los casos las mismas condiciones de salir tendrían que tener todos la misma probabilidad.

Comment: Lo que te vendría bien es un Test Unitario, pero con una función que puede retornar una gran variedad de números en cierto rango, lo mejor es hacer una prueba unitaria de rango, por ejemplo del 8 al 12. Aun así apoyo el comentario de @FranciscoRomero

Answer (score 1):

Para probar puedes hacer una funcion como la siguiente y podrás sacar las estadisticas que necesites

```js
function a(n){
  var b = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (parseInt(n) - n/4) + n/4));
  
  return b;
}

function test(){

  var cont=1;
  var numero = parseInt($("#busca").val(), 10);
  var n = parseInt($("#n").val(), 10);
  var random;
  var encontrado = false;
  var limite = parseInt($("#limite").val(), 10);

  do{
  random = a(n);
  console.log(cont+". "+random);
  if(random==numero){
    encontrado=true;
    break;
    }
  }while(cont++ <= limite)

  if(encontrado)
    console.log("Ya salio el numero " + numero);
  else
    console.log("No salio el numero " + numero);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

N:<input type="text" id="n" value="20"><br>
Esperar: <input type="text" id="busca" value="10"><br>
Iteraciones: <input type="text" id="limite" value="50">
<input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Test" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Según [esto](http://html5index.org/ECMAScript%20-%20Math.html):

> random()
>
> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or
>   equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with
>   approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an
>   implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no
>   arguments.

Es decir, la probabilidad de cualquier número dentro del intervalo  0 a 1 (sin incluir el 1) sigue de forma aproximada una distribución uniforme, lo cual significa que cualquier número debería tener la misma probabilidad de aparecer. Si bien puede parecer una obviedad, esto no significa que ejecutando tu algoritmo un número determinado de veces, vayas a obtener con seguridad un determinado número, significa que a medida que sigas ejecutándolo (es decir tus intentos tiendan a infinito), las apariciones de cada número debieran tender a ser las mismas.